# Change auto generated CSS dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, ionic3

Could you tell me how can I change the css dynamically? Here the problem is, the css has been generated by the framework itself. So I cannot declare or change it.

*This is at runtime:*

[image]

I need to pick `swiper-pagination-bullets` class and need to give bottom value conditionally. Like so:

*Note:* this is just pseudo:

```
If="data!=null" {     
   .swiper-pagination-bullets {
            bottom: 190px !important;
        }
}
else{
  .swiper-pagination-bullets {
            bottom: 150px !important;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried !important inside @media queries?  This may work and make it responsive at the same time

Comment: How that links with media queries? I need to use this on a mobile device. There is no device size change here. Any clue? @Jonny

Comment: I was unaware it was mobile only.  But if you declare a change at a specific resolution it may bypass and help.

Comment: No. No resolution or device size change here. I just need to apply same class differently according to the condition.I have shown it in pseudo mode above. @Jonny

Comment: Is there an actual data attribute on the element that is present or not present, or has a specific value you can match? If so, you can target using a CSS attribute selector. Sass compiles to CSS so it can't read data from the DOM and apply logic, you can only create conditionals within Sass itself that do or don't match conditions in the markup.

Comment: Is there an actual data attribute on the element that is present or not present? No. That is the issue. On both occasions, it shows same `html/css` as shown on runtime image above. @jwfrench

Comment: Do you control parent markup? Can you render swiper-pagination div in your own div?

Comment: First, it is class, not css. Second, you can add/remove a class by `[class.foo]="true/false"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Duannx mentioned in the comments, you could conditionally add a class in the `ion-slides` element, and then apply the css style rule to the pager based on that class.

```
<ion-slides pager="true" [class.with-data]="data" ...>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="...">
        <!-- ... -->
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

You'd need to change `[class.with-data]="data"` and replace it by the real property from your component, but then you could use it in the SCSS file to change the styles of the pager:

```
ion-slides.with-data .swiper-pagination-bullets {     
    bottom: 190px !important;
}

ion-slides:not(.with-data) .swiper-pagination-bullets {
    bottom: 150px !important;
}
```

Comment: Oh.. This is awesome. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to hear that @Sampath :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing CSS dynamically, it would be better to override it instead by dynamically injecting a stylesheet into the page at runtime.

```
const style = document.createElement('style');
const bottom = condition ? 190 : 150;
style.insertRule(`.swiper-pagination-bullets { bottom: ${bottom}px; }`, 1);
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

I'd try to avoid using `!important`. If you inject a stylesheet in the manner shown above, it will already take precedence over the existing style due to it appearing later on the page, assuming the same selector specificity.

Or else you can try to artificially increase the specificity by doing `.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets` (repeat as you deem fit). If that fails to work, then use `!important`.

Code for stylesheet injection taken from [here](https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really like to do it in Angular/ Ionic way. The accepted answer does that. +1 though :)

Comment: You're welcome (: I wasn't aware that you wanted an Angular/Ionic way else I wouldn't have suggested it. Perhaps you could add those keywords into the title or question in addition to the tags in future (: